# present a (play) script

Tags: html, css

This is really difficult to search for because any query involving "script" returns only `<script>` stuff and any query involving "play" returns video-player stuff.

I would like to present a script on a site, this kind of script:

```
MR. FOO     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

BAR         Duis tristique ac sem in finibus. Etiam in viverra nunc, sed tempus eros. In augue nisi,
            congue dapibus rhoncus nec, laoreet sit amet enim. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora
            torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.

MR. FOO     Phasellus id ornare metus. Nulla venenatis lectus quis ligula sodales ullamcorper. Nullam
            ullamcorper sollicitudin dui, at commodo orci pellentesque et.

BAR         Quisque placerat dolor ut tempus ullamcorper.

MR. FOO     Aenean eu ornare turpis.
```

I thought of using `<dl>` and a couple styles for it

```css
dt {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    width: 100px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

dd {
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<dl>
<dt>MR. FOO</dt><dd>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</dd>
<dt>BAR</dt><dd>Duis tristique ac sem in finibus. Etiam in viverra nunc, sed tempus eros. In augue nisi, congue dapibus rhoncus nec, laoreet sit amet enim. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</dd>
<dt>MR. FOO</dt><dd>Phasellus id ornare metus. Nulla venenatis lectus quis ligula sodales ullamcorper. Nullam ullamcorper sollicitudin dui, at commodo orci pellentesque et.</dd>
<dt>BAR</dt><dd>Quisque placerat dolor ut tempus ullamcorper.</dd>
<dt>MR. FOO</dt><dd>Aenean eu ornare turpis.</dd>
</dl>
```

Feels quite abusive of `<dl>` though.

Is there a better element and styling combination?

Better for

- conforming to expectations of how the element should be used
- more well-used (I couldn't find examples of HTML scripts, but there might already be a common practice)
- avoiding potential formatting bugs/conflicts with surrounding content (idk if float may cause me problems later)

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/common-idioms-without-dedicated-elements.html#conversations

Comment: A table would be acceptable here

Comment: The most upvoted answer on the duplicate also uses `dl`. @mplungjan do you know why that answer `float: left;`s _both_ the `dt` and the `dd` ?

Comment: Good question. Look again. I made a snippet. It is likely to allow longer names without pushing the dialogue